# Read python value in HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html

I try to place the value of my sensor in a HTML script (see interface).
I found a example on internet. I would like to have only the blocks with the name Temp en Hum (in running mode are the values visible in the block). But when I delete the graphs, I lost the actual value also.

How can I delete the graphs and hold the actual values in the blocks (temp and Hum)?

[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB5pC.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Flask App </title>

    <!-- Bootstraps Java Scipts Links -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



    <!-- JQuery links  -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <!--High CHART LIVE  -->
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <!--Gauge  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pubnub.github.io/eon/lib/eon.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-5 jumbotron p-2 mx-1">
                <h1 class="sensor1"> Sensor : </h1>
            </div>
            <br>

            <div class="col-5 jumbotron p-2 mx-1">
                <h1 class="sensor2">Sensor :</h1>
            </div>
            <br>



        </div>
    </div>


    <style>
     <!--
        .jumbotron{
            widows: 150px;
            height: 220px;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .row{
            justify-content: center;
        }
    -->

    </style>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Example row of columns -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container-fluid" id="data-temperature">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<br>
<br>
<br>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Example row of columns -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container-fluid" id="data-humidity">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        var chartTemperatue;
        var chartHumidity;

        function requestData()
        {
            // Ajax call to get the Data from Flask
            var requests = $.get('/data');

            var tm = requests.done(function (result)
            {
                // Temperature
                var seriesTemperature = chartTemperatue.series[0],
                    shiftTemperature = seriesTemperature.data.length > 20;

                // Humidity
                var seriesHumidity = chartHumidity.series[0],
                    shiftHumidity = seriesTemperature.data.length > 20;

                // Add the Point
                // Time Temperature\
                var data1 = [];
                data1.push(result[0]);
                data1.push(result[1]);


                // Add the Point
                // Time Humidity
                var data2 = [];
                data2.push(result[0]);
                data2.push(result[2]);


                chartTemperatue.series[0].addPoint(data1, true, shiftTemperature);
                chartHumidity.series[0].addPoint(data2, true, shiftHumidity);
                $(".sensor1").text("");
                $(".sensor1").text("Temperature : " +  Math.round(data1[1]) );

                $(".sensor2").text("");
                $(".sensor2").text("Humidity : " +  Math.round(data2[1]) );

                // call it again after one second
                setTimeout(requestData, 2000);

            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            // --------------Chart 1 ----------------------------
            chartTemperatue = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart:
                    {
                    renderTo: 'data-temperature',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'area',
                    events: {
                        load: requestData
                            }
                    },
                title:
                    {
                    text: 'Temperature'
                    },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 150,
                    maxZoom: 20 * 1000
                        },
                yAxis: {
                    minPadding: 0.2,
                    maxPadding: 0.2,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Value',
                        margin: 80
                            }
                         },
                series: [{
                    color : '#c23d23',
                    lineColor: '#303030',
                    name: 'Temperature',
                    data: []
                }]
            });
            // --------------Chart 1 Ends - -----------------

            chartHumidity = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart:
                    {
                        renderTo: 'data-humidity',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'area',
                        events: {
                            load: requestData
                        }
                    },
                title:
                    {
                        text: 'Humidity'
                    },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 150,
                    maxZoom: 20 * 1000
                },
                yAxis: {
                    minPadding: 0.2,
                    maxPadding: 0.2,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Value',
                        margin: 80
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    lineColor: '#1d82b8',
                    name: 'Humidity',
                    data: []
                }]
            });


        });
    </script>




</body>


</html>
```

Python code

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for,request,redirect, make_response
import random
import json
from time import time
from random import random
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/data', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def data():
    # Data Format
    # [TIME, Temperature, Humidity]

    Temperature = random() * 100
    Humidity = random() * 55

    data = [time() * 1000, Temperature, Humidity]

    response = make_response(json.dumps(data))

    response.content_type = 'application/json'

    return response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please reformulate your question. It's hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If you delete graphs then how you want to see values? It would need to add code which add values in HTML as text. And if you delete graphs then you may have to also delete code which display data in graphs because without graphs it can gives errors (because it can't find graphs) and it may not run rest of code. Did you check JavaScript console in DevTools in Chrome/Firefox? Maybe there are some error message generated by JavaScript code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have updated my question, hopefully it is more clear then before.